# Vector and Scalars

Tags: vectors

The median **PS** of a triangle **PQR** is bisected at **L** and **QL** is produced to meet **PR** at **M**. Prove that:
$$PM=(1/3) PR$$

I tried by taking P as the origin and q and r as position vector of Q and R respectively then found out the position vector of L and S. But i am stuck. please help

Answer (score 1):

> I tried by taking P as the origin and q and r as position vector of Q and R respectively then found out the position vector of L and S.

Then $\,s=(q+r)/2\,$ and $\,l = s/2 = (q+r)/4\,$.

Since $\,M \in PR\,$ let $\,m=\lambda r\,$ where $\,\boxed{\lambda = PM/PR}\,$, and since $\,L \in QM\,$ let $l=\mu q + (1-\mu) m\,$ where $\,\mu = LM/QM\,$.

Given that $\,q, r\,$ are linearly independent (non-zero and not collinear):

$$
l = \frac{q+r}{4}=\mu q +(1-\mu)\lambda r \;\;\implies\;\; \begin{cases} \mu = \frac{1}{4} \\[5px] (1-\mu)\lambda = \frac{1}{4}\end{cases} \;\;\implies\;\; \boxed{\lambda = \frac{1}{3}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce another parallel line and use the converse of the midpoint theorem. It helps to draw a diagram of what's going on. Once you have done those 2 steps you can calculate the length of PR i.t.o. PM.